# I can't find where to add parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

What kind of changes i can make to this code to protect against sql injection?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               string query = "INSERT INTO person (name_,age_)VALUES('" + txtFirstname.Text + "','" + int.Parse(txtAge.Text) + "')";
               DB.OpenConnection();
               DB.SqlQuery = query;
               DB.ExecuteQuery();
               DB.CloseConnection();
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/1070452  If you just type `c# sql parameters` into google you get many, many millions of hits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below

```
    string query = "INSERT INTO person (name_,age_) VALUES(@name,@age)";
    MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand(query);
    m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFirstname.Text);
    m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", int.Parse(txtAge.Text));
```

(OR)

```
m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@name", txtFirstname.Text));
```